# Iteration over list and creating dataframe with each itam of list using Python

Tags: python

I am not having hands on experience in python. Hope some one of you experties will help me. 
This is the first 5 rows of my dataframe.

```
Date        ClientID    Name                  Count
2016-11-21  LMN003007   Thomas Ltd -Nariman     4
2016-11-21  LMN003013   Wagonlit  - Gurgaon     1
2016-11-21  LMN003015   Kuoni DEL               4
2016-11-21  LMN003021   Lmk Services Pvt Ltd.   17
2016-11-21  LMN003023   Emira - Dubai           1
```

Actually I am trying to find out lowest and highest prediction interval for count for each client. For that I have consider last 90 days data. 
So each client is showing their counts at most 90 times. There may be a case where clients are not showing counts. Now I have to iterate my PI function for each client.
For that I have done following script.

```
list = []
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if row[1] not in list:
        list.append(row[1])
```

which gives me list of LMN

```
def PI(lst):
    for i in list:
            print(i)
            df1= df[df['ClientName'].isin([i])]
            num_items = len(lst)
            mean = sum(lst) / num_items
            differences = [x - mean for x in lst]
            sq_differences = [d ** 2 for d in differences]
            ssd = sum(sq_differences)
            variance = ssd / num_items
            sd = np.sqrt(variance)
            LPI = mean - (2*sd)
            UPI = mean + (2*sd)
            return LPI, UPI
lst1 = df1.TicketCount
PI(lst1)
```

This gives me in output, First LMN, i.e 003007 and df1 considers my last LMN.
Actually I am so much confused how iterate through my list of LMN

If anyone help me then it would be gr8.!!!. Please help.

Comment: I kinda couldn't understand your question... In pandas, your first script could be re-written as `df['ClientId'].unique()`. It will give you a list of ClientId

Comment: The first thing I see is that the `return` statement is inside the `for` loop, which would mean that your function `PI` exits after the first iteration. Is that an error that happened during copying the code here?